# How to set datepicker value into firebase?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, jquery-ui, google-cloud-firestore

I have a string field called date in firestore and how to use [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) datepicker to set a new date and overwrite the existing value in date field? Example for date field in firestore:
[example-dateFirestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuv4S.png)

In my html I have created a table with Date that will display the value from firestore.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="setDate">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Change Date</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In my JavaScript (.js) file I've created a button dynamically and added it to the table under 'Change Date'. I tried to set **onclick** event to the button to select a new date whenever the button is click and using [set](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#reading_and_writing_data) to overwrite the date field with the new date value in firebase. However, I'm getting this error in console [console-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uyLc.png).

```
const chgDate = document.querySelector('#setDate');

var newRow   = chgDate.insertRow();

var name = newRow.insertCell(0);
var oldDate  = newRow.insertCell(1);
var datebtn = newRow.insertCell(2);

var a_name  = document.createTextNode(data.data().name);
var a_oldDate = document.createTextNode(data.data().date);
var btn = document.createElement("input");
    btn.setAttribute("type","button");
    btn.setAttribute("id","datebtn");
    btn.setAttribute("value","Change Date");
    btn.onclick = getdate();

    function getdate(){
        var setDate = $('#datebtn').datepicker({
            uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4', 
            iconsLibrary: 'materialicons',
            dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
        });
        //set new value to firebase
        db.collection('Posts').doc('date').set(setDate);
    }

     name.appendChild(a_name);
     oldDate.appendChild(a_oldDate);
     datebtn.appendChild(btn);
```

Is there a way I can set a new date into firebase?

Comment: This is a little confusing. jQuery itself does not have a `.datepicker()` function. jQuery UI does, and Bootstrap does and they work in different ways. Please clarify what libraries you're using and what errors you're seeing.

Comment: You should also add a .then() and a .catch() clause to the db.collection.doc.set statement to see the results (either an error or a success object).